# NPM packages could not able to install it in React -native project

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating a project in react-native, As a part of it, I am trying to install an npm package
Ex: $ npm install --save is-reachable

After installing the NPM package, I am trying to run react native project
'react-native run-ios'
I am getting the following error:

[image: Unable to module map]

Help me to get out of this issue. Without npm package install, I could move to proceed further

Comment: Have you tried to follow those 3 steps suggestion?

Comment: yes I have tried those 3 steps, but still I am facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

OS is a node module, React Native doesn't rely on node, but on V8 and Safaris runtime for the Javascript runtime. This means you can't use the `clean-stack` node module in react-native.

Comment: Then How can i use oauth1.0a in react-native?For oauth-1.0a we need 3 npm packages to be installed. 1. npm install oauth-1.0a 2. npm install --save request 3. npm install --save request . I could not able to install "crypto and request npm package". Kindly help me on this to acheive this oauth1.0a to get oauth_signature              https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a

Comment: @RamKumarBalasubramanian there is a react native version: https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth

Comment: this react-native package only supports only 5 servers not the own servers

Comment: You have no workaround around this, you need to file an issue in this module then or fork it, but you won't be able to installed node dependencies on React Native